# Find distinct field in multiple same collections mongodb

Tags: mongodb, distinct

I have 7 collections in one database that the collections are the **same** and I have to find a unique field in those collections and count it or show it in a new collection named `result`.

I tried lookup but it it did not work. Can anyone guide me how to do the job?

These are 7 collections: `20200309-20200310-20200311-20200312-20200313-20200314-20200315` and `result` is the collection for store the result of query.

```
col : 20200309 
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e6f7c7c0371c86b8737628b"),
    "sid" : 13328,
    "trans-id" : "PROV_158374123364907198165",
    "status" : "1",
    "base-price-point" : "6000",
    "msisdn" : "989115506327",
    "keyword" : "",
    "validity" : 0,
    "next_renewal_date" : "",
    "shortcode" : "",
    "billed-price-point" : "",
    "trans-status" : 0,
    "chargeCode" : "AVMREWCAVMAW6000",
    "datetime" : "2020-03-09 11:37:13.649",
    "event-type" : "1.5",
    "channel" : "system"
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e6f7c7c0371c86b8737628c"),
    "sid" : 13328,
    "trans-id" : "PROV_158374123384007267165",
    "status" : "1",
    "base-price-point" : "6000",
    "msisdn" : "989107351827",
    "keyword" : "",
    "validity" : 0,
    "next_renewal_date" : "",
    "shortcode" : "",
    "billed-price-point" : "",
    "trans-status" : 0,
    "chargeCode" : "AVMREWCAVMAW6000",
    "datetime" : "2020-03-09 11:37:13.840",
    "event-type" : "1.5",
    "channel" : "system"
}
 col : 20200310 
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e6f7d140371c86b873e6bce"),
    "sid" : 13328,
    "trans-id" : "PROV_158383144246275616515",
    "status" : "1",
    "base-price-point" : "6000",
    "msisdn" : "989909789746",
    "keyword" : "",
    "validity" : 0,
    "next_renewal_date" : "",
    "shortcode" : "",
    "billed-price-point" : "",
    "trans-status" : 0,
    "chargeCode" : "AVMREWCAVMAW6000",
    "datetime" : "2020-03-10 12:40:42.462",
    "event-type" : "1.5",
    "channel" : "system"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e6f7d140371c86b873e6bcf"),
    "sid" : 13328,
    "trans-id" : "PROV_158382430015338271227",
    "status" : "1",
    "base-price-point" : "6000",
    "msisdn" : "989901812412",
    "keyword" : "",
    "validity" : 0,
    "next_renewal_date" : "",
    "shortcode" : "",
    "billed-price-point" : "",
    "trans-status" : 0,
    "chargeCode" : "AVMREWCAVMAW6000",
    "datetime" : "2020-03-10 10:41:40.153",
    "event-type" : "1.5",
    "channel" : "system"
}
```

and there is 5 collections like above

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by `find a unique feild in those collections and count it or show it`, can you show a sample of what the output should look like and a query you've tried?

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: i want to see  distinct("msisdn",{"status":"1"}).length  but i can do this for one collection i want to do this for 7 collctions at the same time to see that how many "msisdn" with status 1

Comment: I edited your title to be more explaining what you actually want to achieve. Also edited the text as it contained a lot of stuff that was not needed or was unclear in what you wanted to explain. I hope that helps to understand your question way better now.

Comment: Are there any indexes defined on the collection fields?

Answer (score 0):

The following script can be used to get distinct `msisdn` values in an array and the count. Run the script from the *mongo shell*.

For this to run efficiently, there needs to be an index on the two fields `msisdn` and `status` as: `{ status: 1, msisdn: 1}`. The index needs to be created on all the collections. Note the indexes are *not* required in case the collections have just few thousand documents.

```
collections = [ "20200309", "20200310", // ... ]
combined = [ ]

for (let coll of collections) {
  combined = combined.concat( db.getCollection(coll).distinct( "msisdn", { status: "1" } ) )
}

combined = [...new Set(combined) ]
print('Combined count:', combined.length)
```

The `combined = [...new Set(combined) ]` statement removes duplicates from the combined distinct values from the seven collections.